# Restrict calls to specific packages

Tags: android

We want to build a platform, where third-party devs can link into, after getting our blessing.

The core app `A` should thus be able to communicate both way with third party apps `X`, `Y`, … .

We could require the third parties to share their code, so we can compile it so we can use `android:protectionLevel="signature"`. This is not good for several reasons:

- we don't want to be in the way when they want to upgrade their module
- we don't want them to have to disclose their code
- we don't trust `X` to not abuse `A`'s access right against `Y`

We could check the `callingPackage` and check if it is signed by the expected key. Unfortunately the `callingPackage` is

- known to `ContentProvider`
- unknown to `Service` (and `BroadcastReceiver`)
- known to `Activity` if called using `startActivityForResult()` but `sAFR()` is not available in `Service` for example.

Is there a way to expose a Service/Activity/ContentProvider to only a set of developers (as per package signature)? If not, can the `callingPackage` be faked or is it reliable where it is provided?